# Como definir codificação UTF-8 em arquivos data.sql para inicialização do H2 data base com Spring?

Tags: utf-8, spring-jpa, h2database

Tenho uma aplicação Spring JPA com banco de dados H2. 
Criei um arquivo data.sql com alguns `INSERTS` e este script está sendo executado normalmente na inicialização da aplicação, porém os caracteres especiais estão sendo corrompidos quando inseridos nas tabelas.

Adicionei no `application.properties` a propriedade abaixo mas o erro ainda persiste

```
spring.datasource.sqlScriptEncoding=UTF-8
```

Os dados estão ficando na tabela desta forma:

```
ID      NOME  
1   Afeganist�o
2   �frica do Sul
```

O mesmo script rodado manualmente não apresenta nenhum problema na gravação.

Comment: Vou deixar o link de um projeto que fiz, dá uma olhada nos 4 arquivos e ve se te ajuda; [link_do_projeto](https://github.com/kalbzero/TradeCardsDoc/tree/master/src/main/resources)

Comment: Obrigada, dei uma olhada nos seus arquivos mas não resolveu o meu problema.

Comment: Só para encerrar o tópico... Encontrei o motivo do erro, as configurações estavam ok, o problema ocorria pois eu estava gerando o arquivo data.sql em outro editor e adicionando a pasta. Ao abrir o arquivo no eclipse notei que os dados haviam sido corrompidos ao adicionar o arquivo na pasta do projeto e não durante a gravação. Resolvi o problema salvando o arquivo direto no eclipse.

Comment: Coloque o que aconteceu como resposta sua, para os outros usuários poderem ver e ter ideia do que aconteceu :)

Answer (score 0):

Só para encerrar o tópico... Encontrei o motivo do erro, as configurações estavam ok, o problema ocorria pois eu estava gerando o arquivo data.sql em outro editor e adicionando a pasta. Ao abrir o arquivo no eclipse notei que os dados haviam sido corrompidos ao adicionar o arquivo na pasta do projeto e não durante a gravação. Resolvi o problema salvando o arquivo direto no eclipse.